# Populate special Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode

I'm parsing a JSON in Swift project and I want to put the data inside a special array with fixed keys (x, y). I'm a Swift beginner and I'm not sure of the correct syntax.

I've tried to normally push data inside the array, but the risult is wrong.

Inside this function:

```swift
func updateDashboardData(json : JSON){
     for i  in 0 ..< json.count {
          let tag = json[i]["tag"] 
          let value = json[i]["value"]     
     }
}
```

I want to generate this array:

```swift
let data = [
            (x: tag, y: value),
            (x: tag, y: value),
            (x: tag, y: value)
        ]
```

Which is the correct syntax for pushing the data in this way?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It looks like you want to use a tuple, so assuming you have an array `data` then in the `for` loop you can do `data.append((tag,value))`. Tuples are mostly for intermediate storage so even better would be to use a struct, `struct TagAndValue { let tag: String; let value: String }` as an example, and create an array of them. `data.append(TagAndValue(tag: tag, value: value))`

Answer (score -3):

You should use Object Mapper. Here is the link
https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper